# polite request: We would ask

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I found in a book the sentence "We would ask you to clear the balance immediately." Is this correct English or should it rather be: "We would like to ask you to clear the balance immediately"?

Comment: For *interpersonal relationships* topics (as seems to be the central issue here), check out [interpersonal.se].

Comment: Sorry: I found the following sentence in a book ...

Comment: I understand, and more context might help. But the issue doesn't seem to be about language - it's about social customs or manners. Both sentences are grammatical ("correct English", as you put it), and with the appropriate context, both can be polite requests.

Comment: It might not be apparent at first glance, but Stack Exchange sites are deliberately split into silos of information. The intention is to collate a database of questions about particular (broad) topics such as English, Maths, Programming, and so on, together with well-supported answers to those questions. The links in the "?" menu at the top of the page go into more depth, and the so-called 'hamburger' menu takes you to the various SE communities. Each community has a "What topics can I ask about here?" page that describes the kinds of questions that community is intended to collate. ...

Comment: ... You can get to the page from the "?" menu by clicking on the "Help Centre" menu item. Note that to access the appropriate page, you need to first land on a page in that community before clicking on the menu.

Comment: I found the sentence in a book about English business correspondence (Unit: Reminders) I was wondering about the missing word "like" and thought it was a language question.

Comment: In that case, the question should include more text that explains the point of interest. For example, you might list a few sentences that exclude the word "like" that demonstrate rudeness (explain why they would be considered rude), then list similar sentences that include the word "like" and demonstrate that these are considered to be polite. You can then ask why the context of the original quote (without "like") suggests that it was treated as polite.

Comment: Either appears correct to me, but as an American, the first strikes me as being "more British", and the second "more American". It is even more likely that an American firm asking this in correspondence would write simply "Please clear this balance immediately."

Comment: @Lawrence I'm genuinely confused as to why you think this is IP rather than language usage. sig clearly states the phrase came from a book and they want to know if the usage is correct. This isn't on topic at IPS and the poor soul would probably be redirected back to here. Unless comments have been deleted it seems to be you who introduced the topic of politeness/rudeness, not the OP. You've said both are grammatical, couldn't you explain for him why the first is so? I would if I understood grammar well enough, and here you've spent all this time commenting and not shared the info sig seeks.

Comment: @Spagirl Thanks for asking. At first glance, the OP has a point regarding "like". However, the first quote said softly with a smile could be considered polite; the second spoken harshly with a stern demeanor wouldn't be the epitome of customer relations. That's the gist of what I meant - the interpersonal aspect dominates this question. The language portion is simply the medium of communication, rather than the meat of the question itself. Having said that, you've pointed out something I missed: *politeness* was irrelevant to the question; it was 'correctness' that they were wondering about.

Comment: @sig '*Would*' (past tense of *will*) is often used for politeness, to pad out an otherwise curt statement such as "Clear the balance immediately". Can you please add more context to your quotes? Try 2 to 3 lines of dialogue to start with. "We would ask *that* you ..." sounds better than "We would ask you to ...", but depending on how the rest goes, it *might* work.

Comment: @Spagirl (About introducing the topic of *politeness* - I took my cue from the first word of the question's title "polite request: We would ask".)

Comment: @Spagirl I hope I've addressed your comment above. I don't always pick up the unspoken question (and [here's](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/450062/142322) another that took some digging). We got there in the end with the other question, but trying to work it out via dialogue sometimes generates more heat than light :/ . It's always good communicating with you, I'd like you to know. But if I'm frustrating even you, maybe I need to take a bit of a break from the site.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, you've addressed most of it, though I still don't understand why you would put so much thought and effort and consideration into this but not tidy it up as an answer where it could be both permanent and upvoted.

Comment: @Spagirl Done. :)

Comment: @Lawrence so I see! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about this sentence:

> We would ask you to clear the balance immediately.

It appears from comments to your question that you're wondering whether "would ask" works there, as opposed to "would *like to* ask".

You also mention the topic of politeness in the title of your question. Padding out the basic "Clear the balance immediately." with little words certainly fits in with diplomatic language:

> 4. Use little words to soften your statements
>    [- 5 Tips for Polite and Diplomatic Language](https://www.londonschool.com/blog/5-tips-polite-and-diplomatic-language/)

The word *would* can be used in the following ways:

> **would** *modal verb*
>
> - 3 Expressing a desire or inclination. *I would love to work in America.*
> - 4 Expressing a polite request. *Would you pour the wine, please?*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/would)

I think both definitions apply here. The intended request is:

- We ( ) ask you to clear the balance immediately.

Adding the word *would* softens this somewhat. It might look as if it is simply indicating that at some stage in the future, the above request would be made (just as your "would like to" variant does). However, in BrE especially, and perhaps in other dialects, the context might dictate that this *is* the request, just delivered politely. Here's another example in print:

> All are welcome and admission is free. This is one of Dr ...'s rare public appearances in the UK. In order to secure your place at the lecture, we would ask you to register in advance by filling in the form below and returning it before 24 February. ...
> [- a sample quoted in The Pragmatics of Translation, edited by Leo Hickey](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=RLgWcp-8a74C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22we%20would%20ask%20you%22%20polite&source=bl&ots=CDjUpLPnOS&sig=j4As2t2rftVCNmhReJZFSSekROw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim8tSqqc7bAhULErwKHQ8KDA8Q6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=%22we%20would%20ask%20you%22%20polite&f=false)

The book goes on to identify problems with mixing genres when that text used as an 'academic announcement' rather than as 'show business publicity material, but the use of "*we would ask you*" passes without comment.

Here's another example:

> To ensure everyone enjoys their day supporting the club we'd like to take this opportunity to remind fans that they are representing Middlesbrough Football Club at all times, and we would ask you to help us in ensuring the Riverside is a safe place for all.
> [- Middlesbrough Football Club is issuing a polite reminder to fans that the use of pyrotechnics at the Riverside Stadium is not allowed](https://www.mfc.co.uk/news/middlesbrough-football-club-is-issuing-a-polite-reminder-to-fans-that-the-use-of-pyrotechnics-at-the)

To sum up: the original works grammatically. It has the same sense as your alternate "would like to" wording.

Comment: Compare 'Common use of _would_ before verbs of saying and thinking, to make a statement sound less definite [brusque]: We would ask passengers to have their tickets ready for inspection (Would is further commonly used before verbs of saying and thinking so that a statement sounds more indirect )' [Swan 1995: 247, 160]

Answer (score 0):

> "We would ask you to clear the balance immediately." Is this correct
> English or should it rather be: "We would like to ask you to clear the
> balance immediately"?
> The second is too long.

"Clear the balance immediately." (command)

"We ask you to clear the balance immediately." (direct and to the point)

"We would ask you to clear the balance immediately." (slightly softened)

"We would like you to clear the balance immediately." (even more softened)

"If you don't clear the balance immediately, a kitten will die."  (emotional blackmail)