# The reason... is you?

Tags: verb-agreement, lyrics, songs

In *Hoobastank*'s *The Reason*, a lyric is

> And the Reason is you...

Is that sentence (grammatically) correct? I'm asking because, you know... *You are the reason*.

Specifically, should "is" in the quote agree instead with "you" (i.e. "the reason *are* you")?

**Answered.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the use of "is" in this quotation is grammatically correct. Compare the well-known example "It is I/me", where people argue about whether to use "I" or "me", but never about whether to use "is" or "am". A verb agrees with its subject: the subject here is "the reason", which is singular. In modern English, only pronouns (like *I, you,* or in relative clauses *who*) can trigger first-person or second-person agreement on an associated verb. Because "the reason" is not a pronoun, it has to trigger third-person agreement. So it is correct to use the third-person singular form.